# Standard Deviation of a Row

Tags: sql-server

How do I find the standard deviation of a row in SQL Server? I'm trying to find the standard deviation for the image below but I'm unsure how.

Would I do STDEV on the total of the row? I'd want another column at the end showing the standard deviation for the entire year. I saw in Excel someone did =(STDEV(C4:N4)).

[image]

Comment: You mean STDEV of all the numeric values in all the columns of a single row? STDEV acts on a group of values. If you do it on a single value (a total) the deviation is 0 (or undefined, depending on who you ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate functions such as `SUM` or [`STDEV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stdev-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) operate over rows.

You can use `CROSS APPLY` to unpivot the columns to rows to calculate an aggregate on them

```
SELECT t.*,
       ca.StdDev
FROM   YourTable t
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT STDEV(Val)
                    FROM   (VALUES (JANUARY),
                                   (FEBRUARY),
                                   (MARCH),
                                   (APRIL),
                                   (MAY),
                                   (JUNE),
                                   (JULY),
                                   (AUGUST),
                                   (SEPTEMBER),
                                   (OCTOBER),
                                   (NOVEMBER),
                                   (DECEMBER) ) v(Val)) ca(StdDev)
```

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated.